# Infinite loop in comparing Time Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, time, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've been trying to create code in PowerShell that's gonna run if the time is below a specific time but upon experimenting it always gets stuck in an infinite loop executing even when the condition is already not satisfied

here's my code:

```
$a = Get-Date
Write-Host $a
[datetime]$time = "05/12/2016 1:57:00 AM"

DO
{
    if($a -gt $time) {break}
    Write-Host "not yet time"
    if($a -gt $time) {break}
}while( $a -le $time)
CLS
Write-Host "done"
```

But it still is running even at 1:59 AM already. Any ideas on how to properly compare time? I want it to run till a specific time or I want it to run at least 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only assign the output from `Get-Date` to `$a` *once*, it's never updated, and you're performing the exact same comparison (times 3) every time the loop runs.

Call `Get-Date` in the loop body or conditional to get the updated time:

```
[datetime]$time = "05/12/2016 1:57:00 AM"

do {
    Write-Host "not yet time"
}while($(Get-Date) -le $time)
cls
Write-Host "done"
```